# How do you programmatically add members to a single Google IAP access list?

Tags: google-iam, terraform-provider-gcp, google-iap

I have 2 terraformed/k8s-yaml services that have IAP enabled.

In order to maintain the member access list between infra refreshes (when the load balancers get destroyed and so the access list gets wiped) I have assigned the IAM role 'IAP-secured Web App User' to the relevant users.

e.g.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "bob_iap_web_app_user" {
   role   = "roles/iap.httpsResourceAccessor"
   member = "user:bob.cat@meow.com"
}
```

However this allows access to all IAP protected APIs within the project. Is there a filter you can add to only allow access to a particular load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Wait for https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/2613 to be implemented.
2. You can use [conditional grants](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/cloud-iap-context-aware-access-howto#using_hostname_and_path_conditions) at the project level to set up something like "bob.cat has access if request host is meow.com, alice.dog has access if request host is woof.com".

--Matthew, Google Cloud IAP engineering

Comment: As of October 2019, the google_iap_web_iam_* resources are available for terraform-provider-google. See docs here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/iap_web_iam